# How to create 1400px fixed width website by BootStrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have PSD file that width is 1400px. I want create that website by BootStrap 3. But Bootstap default width is 1170px. How can I make my 1400px website by BootStrap. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Option #1 :

Add a breakpoint for devices with `width > 1430px` (1400px + 2*15px padding) :

Bootstrap 3:

```
@media (min-width: 1430px) {
  .container {
    width: 1400px;
  }
}
```

Bootstrap 4:

```
@media (min-width: 1430px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
  }
}
```

### Option #2 :

[**Customize your Bootstrap assets**](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints), changing these variables :

- `@screen-lg: 1400px`
- `@container-large-desktop: ((1370px + @grid-gutter-width))`

And download it.

Comment: It won't break anything, as Bootstrap 3 define everything in percents, except `.container` size.

Comment: You are correct. For some reason I was thinking there was a size above screen-lg.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to make a custom Bootstrap 3 build.

Look at the [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) and [Container Sizes](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes) section Under Bootstraps customize page.

Under ***Grid System*** you may want to change the `@grid-gutter-width` property you may not this is a preference. `@grid-gutter-width` is the width between your columns default is 30px.

Under ***Container Sizes*** you will have to change the `@container-large-desktop` property. The default is `((1140px + @grid-gutter-width))`.

**I would suggest changing the `@container-large-desktop` property to `((1370px + @grid-gutter-width))` and leaving the `@grid-gutter-width` at the default.**

If you decide to change the `@grid-gutter-width` just subtract the new`@grid-gutter-width` from 1400. For example if you make the`@grid-gutter-width: 50px` then make `@container-large-desktop: ((1350px + @grid-gutter-width))` ***1400 - 50 = 1350***

I hope this helps.